# How to embed mysql interactive WYSIWYG in my own website

Tags: php, mysql, wysiwyg

I tried using Ckeditor WYSIWYG and TinyEditor but couldn't get it to work in my PHP application.

Ckeditor failed because of the lack of PHP support in its new version. And TinyEditor doesn't have a code highlighter like below in it.

```
THIS IS CODE
```

I need to input my post content into mysql database and bring it back to display. But i couldn't found any appropriate one. (CodeHighlighter is preferable but atleast code must be shown differently).

How do i do that? How do I insert a formatted HTML post into MySQL and bring it back? Along with code highlighting.

I'd prefer it if I didn't have to use any WYSIWYG, just tell me how to implement code highlighting.

Comment: You could try to use Codemirror (textarea syntax highlighter that works as you type) inside TinyMCE (normal WYSIWYG editor). Sounds complicated but possible.

Comment: If you just want to apply SyntaxHL to some code using PHP, [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) could be useful for you. It supports lots of languages and is quite easy to use. But it is **not** an interactive text editor.

Comment: "lack of PHP support in its new version" - hmm? And why would you need it for a client side library?